# pip modules not installing properly - linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

While trying to install a python module using pip3 install (lets for example say pyaudio)
gives the output:

`pip3 install pyaudio`

`Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.2.11)`

but when trying to import it using Sublime Text like this: `import PyAudio`
Gives the output:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
```

`File "/home/Ved/Python Projects/test.py", line 1, in <module>`
`import PyAudio`

`ImportError: No module named PyAudio`

`[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]`

`[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/Ved/Python Projects/test.py"]`

`[dir: /home/Ved/Python Projects]`

`[path: /home/Ved/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin]`

Any Help? is this because im using.....Linux?
(Psst.... this is my first time askign question in StackOverFlow so sorry if i did something wrong)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+module+named+PyAudio%22

Answer (score 1):

use

```
import pyaudio
```

don't use

```
import PyAudio
```

Comment: OMG am i really that dumb

Comment: But i think there is still a problem cuz i cant import speechrecognition

Comment: Open a new question for it, with what you have done and what is the error. Would be glad to help you